# React - Rerender on props change / dynamically changing css without rerender

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a requirement to hide the page content on a React Application when the navigation is shown/hidden.

For this we pass down a prop to the component and handle the display css in styled components like this:

```
<PageContent isOpen={isOpen}>
```

```
const PageContent = styled.div`
  display: ${props => (props.isOpen ? 'none' : 'block')};
`;
```

Whilst this works fine, the inner page content is rerendered when the prop changes, which is expected but not desired.

In this case the page content includes some content that is fetched from an API and therefore every time the navigation is opened/closed we are rendering the content again and fetching from the API again which is not needed.

Is there a way to dynamically control hiding/showing the main content holder, without re-rendering every time? Or should we be looking more into the component that does the fetching and not updating that?

Comment: add more code, so we can help better.

Comment: I don't think there is much to add there. It is well explained and adding more code to the above would bloat the question for no reason. The important part is that you have a child component that does not care about the parent props but is rerendered. See my answer below which will be accepted when I can...

Comment: i will create a example to show you how to fix your problem just give some time.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a component css to display hidden should only hide it visually but the components should still be mounted on the DOM tree.

Perhaps your API fetching is taking place with every rerender when it instead should only be taking place when the components mounts.

Comment: I thought the same, but it definitely rerenders the entire component tree beneath

Comment: The rerender is expected. The root of your problem is that data fetching is happening on rerender instead of on mount. Make things can cause a component to rerender, including this css change, and you don't want to fetch data each time. Wrap your data fetching inside a componentDidMount method or in a useEffect with empty depedencies array if you are using hooks.

Comment: Even with an empty dependency array for the useEffect hook, the component is still fully rerendered and therefore the mounted again and the API is called

Answer (score 0):

Exactly thats an expected behavior what you can do is not use CSS to hide the component, but rather return and empty Fragment, if the "isOpen" is true, preventing the API calls, if these calls are from an inner component

```
 <>
 </>
```

if possible

Comment: The same would still happen here, you'd just check the value and return nothing but then return the page content when the value changes, therefore calling the full component try and full rerender including the API calls

Answer (score 0):

I ended up wrapping the main content which didn't care about the parent prop in a `PureComponent`.

> React's PureComponent does a shallow compare on the component's props and state. If nothing has changed, it prevents the rerender of the component. If something has changed, it rerenders the component.

Answer (score 0):

every time a component trigger state change all it's child will re-render even if the child doesn't relay on that state. To solve the issue you need to wrap the child Component with `React.memo` for functional Component or use `PureComponent` for class components. this will check for props change and re-render the child .

here a example of component fetching data on mount and have a button which trigger state on `click`: [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-ganguly-4d90b?file=/src/MyData.js)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import MyData from "./MyData";

const fakePromise = () =>
  new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("data returned");
    }, 2000);
  });
export default function App() {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await fakePromise();
        setData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        throw error;
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={{ display: hidden ? "none" : "block" }}>I am visible</div>
      <button onClick={() => setHidden(!hidden)}>Toggle Visiblity</button>
      {data && <MyData data={data} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

in the example as you can see `MyData` component doesn't relay on hidden state but it will re-render if we didn't wrap it in `React.memo`.

MyData.js

```
import React from "react";

const MyData = ({ data }) => {
  console.log("render");
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

//export default MyData;

export default React.memo(MyData);
```

note : `React.memo` compare current props and next props and if some of these props is a function or static data `array/object` each time component re-render those will be recreated which will re-render the child  so  you need  to memo those props using hooks like `useCallback` or `useMemo`.

thanks hope this answer your question.